# org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Releasing shared slot parent

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have two jobs, jobA and jobB. When I cancel jobA, jobB fails at the same time. And jobB throws

> org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Releasing shared slot parent

What does it mean and how to fix it?

Flink Version 1.6.0

I have isolated slots by [setting a slot sharing group](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/#task-chaining-and-resource-groups) for my job:

```
someStream.filter(...).slotSharingGroup("name");
```

but it does not work.

Comment: This could indicate a bug in Flink's scheduling logic. Have you tried upgrading to one of the latest Flink versions (1.7.2 or 1.6.4)?

Comment: @TillRohrmann I'm unable to upgrade it since the whole company is using 1.6.0 now. I have submit it to flink jira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem gets solved after upgrading to flink 1.9